# Search array for multiple strings?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I’m searching for IF a string matching the email domains is present in a recordset.

$outsideService is our array of needles to look for:

```
$outsideService = array('guest.booking.com','vrbo.com'); // Add outside services to screen for not having emails in DB
```

My recordset array is $OS as created below:

```
$OS = ($Departing->Results); // Gather recordset  array
```

From that array I create a new array with just the email col:

```
$DepartingOS = array_column($OS, 'email'); // [index, value]
```

Result (haystack):

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => ivchan630@gmail.com
     [1] => mplotn.346854@guest.booking.com
     [2] => 0
 )
```

So now I need to compare to see IF the needle is in the haystack :

```
 if(preg_match($outsideService, $DepartingOS)) {
    echo ’True’;
}
```

This did not work.
I believe the problem is preg_match does not work with an array as the haystack? Meaning I would need to loop the array looking for the needle each time.

But I also tried this method where the needles are set manually and still no luck.

```
if(preg_match('(guest.booking.com|vrbo.com)', $DepartingOS)===1) {
echo 'True';
}
```

Am I using preg_match wrong? How would I search the recordset array for the needles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to do is iterate each of your arrays, checking whether any value of `$outsideService` is located within a value inside `$DepartingOS`. You can do this with a nested [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce), using [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check for a match:

```
$outsideService = array('guest.booking.com','vrbo.com');
$DepartingOS = array('ivchan630@gmail.com', 'mplotn.346854@guest.booking.com', '0');

if (array_reduce($outsideService, function ($c, $OS) use ($DepartingOS) {
    return $c || array_reduce($DepartingOS, function ($c, $DOS) use ($OS) {
        return $c || (strpos($DOS, $OS) !== false);
    }, false);
}, false)) {
    echo "True";
}
```

Output:

```
True
```

This can also be written more simply as a nested `foreach` loop:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($outsideService as $OS) {
    foreach ($DepartingOS as $DOS) {
        if (strpos($DOS, $OS) !== false) {
            $found = true;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
if ($found) {
    echo "True";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fXFBK)

Comment: Yes, this works though it's hard for me to understand (learn). What does the $c reference (abbrevieation)?

Comment: @Burndog I apologise. Sometimes I get carried away with PHPs array functions. Anyway to answer your question, `$c` is an accumulator and it just tracks the current state of whether we have found a match or not; it is the value ultimately returned by `array_reduce`. But I have edited my answer with a simple nested foreach loop which is probably better code to use anyway.